# How to add a block in checkout page in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to add a block on magento default checkout page i.e in **cart.phtml** file.
   So first step I did  is, I added a block of code in checkout.xml file in the section

```
     <reference name="content">
      <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart"> .....
```

Here is my code

```
     <block type="bestseller/bestseller" name="bestseller" template="bestseller/bestseller.phtml"/>
```

and then in second step i just called its child html section as

```
      <div style="width:220px; float:right;"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bestseller');?>   </div>
```

But the problem is when I came to see its frontend I seen this bestseller block is appearing two times on the same checkout page.
I don't know what m doing wrong. !!pLease someone help me !

Comment: where you added these config in xml layout file?

Comment: Put full checkout.xml and cart.phtml in your questions

Comment: <block type="bestseller/bestseller" name="bestseller" template="bestseller/bestseller.phtml"/>
    </checkout_cart_index>. just above the line where checkout_cart_index is closing

Comment: Where cart.phtml???????

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this with no issues, here are my steps:
Step 1: make a **local.xml** file inside your theme inside your layout folder (*yourtheme/layout/local.xml*).

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <checkout_cart_index>
            <reference name="checkout.cart">
                <block type="vendorname_modulename/blockname" name="your.name.here" as="your.name.here" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </checkout_cart_index>
    </layout>
```

Step 2: copy the **cart.phtml** to your theme (mimicking the folder structure: *yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml*)
Step 3: add this line of code inside the cart template.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('your.name.here');
```

As a side note there are many ways to accomplish this,I hope this helps. good luck!